# System.log: main.CRITICAL: Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addChild(): unterminated entity reference

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.4.6

Hey I regularly get this error in my System.log. Can someone help me or say what's the reason?

```
main.CRITICAL: Warning: SimpleXMLElement::addChild(): unterminated entity reference              EB in /var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Convert/ConvertArray.php on line 93 [{"function":"handler","class":"Magento\\Framework\\App\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Convert/ConvertArray.php","line":93,"function":"addChild","class":"SimpleXMLElement","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Convert/ConvertArray.php","line":100,"function":"_assocToXml","class":"Magento\\Framework\\Convert\\ConvertArray","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Convert/ConvertArray.php","line":100,"function":"_assocToXml","class":"Magento\\Framework\\Convert\\ConvertArray","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Convert/ConvertArray.php","line":47,"function":"_assocToXml","class":"Magento\\Framework\\Convert\\ConvertArray","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/opengento/module-gdpr/Service/Export/Renderer/XmlRenderer.php","line":38,"function":"assocToXml","class":"Magento\\Framework\\Convert\\ConvertArray","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/opengento/module-gdpr/Service/Export/Renderer/AbstractRenderer.php","line":37,"function":"render","class":"Opengento\\Gdpr\\Service\\Export\\Renderer\\XmlRenderer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/opengento/module-gdpr/Model/Export/ExportToFile.php","line":62,"function":"saveData","class":"Opengento\\Gdpr\\Service\\Export\\Renderer\\AbstractRenderer","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/opengento/module-gdpr/Model/ExportEntityManagement.php","line":84,"function":"export","class":"Opengento\\Gdpr\\Model\\Export\\ExportToFile","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/opengento/module-gdpr/Cron/ExportEntity.php","line":59,"function":"export","class":"Opengento\\Gdpr\\Model\\ExportEntityManagement","type":"->"},{"function":"execute","class":"Opengento\\Gdpr\\Cron\\ExportEntity","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php","line":368,"function":"call_user_func_array"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php","line":879,"function":"_runJob","class":"Magento\\Cron\\Observer\\ProcessCronQueueObserver","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php","line":840,"function":"tryRunJob","class":"Magento\\Cron\\Observer\\ProcessCronQueueObserver","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-cron/Observer/ProcessCronQueueObserver.php","line":280,"function":"processPendingJobs","class":"Magento\\Cron\\Observer\\ProcessCronQueueObserver","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php","line":88,"function":"execute","class":"Magento\\Cron\\Observer\\ProcessCronQueueObserver","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Invoker/InvokerDefault.php","line":74,"function":"_callObserverMethod","class":"Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Event/Manager.php","line":65,"function":"dispatch","class":"Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Invoker\\InvokerDefault","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Event/Manager/Proxy.php","line":95,"function":"dispatch","class":"Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cron.php","line":86,"function":"dispatch","class":"Magento\\Framework\\Event\\Manager\\Proxy","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-cron/Console/Command/CronCommand.php","line":126,"function":"launch","class":"Magento\\Framework\\App\\Cron","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php","line":298,"function":"execute","class":"Magento\\Cron\\Console\\Command\\CronCommand","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php","line":58,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php","line":138,"function":"___callParent","class":"Magento\\Cron\\Console\\Command\\CronCommand\\Interceptor","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php","line":153,"function":"Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}","class":"Magento\\Cron\\Console\\Command\\CronCommand\\Interceptor","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Cron/Console/Command/CronCommand/Interceptor.php","line":23,"function":"___callPlugins","class":"Magento\\Cron\\Console\\Command\\CronCommand\\Interceptor","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php","line":1040,"function":"run","class":"Magento\\Cron\\Console\\Command\\CronCommand\\Interceptor","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php","line":301,"function":"doRunCommand","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php","line":116,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php","line":171,"function":"doRun","class":"Magento\\Framework\\Console\\Cli","type":"->"},{"file":"/var/www/vhosts/magento2/httpdocs/bin/magento","line":23,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"}] []
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

- Check for special characters or entities in the XML content added
  using the addChild() method and ensure they are properly escaped.
- Validate the XML structure to ensure all tags are properly balanced
  and any attributes are correctly formatted.
- Verify the data being used to generate the XML is clean and does not
  contain unescaped special characters or entities.

Answer (score 0):

**Use htmlspecialchars in secod parameter like below**

```
$xml->addChild($key,htmlspecialchars($value));
```